# How to set value of ListBox as a string

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I have the following code inside a for loop:

```
ComboboxItem itemb = new ComboboxItem();
itemb.Text = item.gameName;
itemb.Value = item.name;

ASCII_FriendList.Items.Add(itemb);
```

ASCII_FriendList is the ListBox and I want to display item.gameName because item.name is a random uuid, therefore is unreadable. The gameName can be recognised pretty easily.

So far I haven't found a solution, what alternative do I have?

Comment: `Add(item.gameName)` ?

Comment: I need to use "name" as value, gameName is just a way to associate the uuid to the value

Comment: But I can not store "name" because it's a string

Comment: Is it WinForms? WPF?   For WPF you should use an ItemTemplate in the xaml.

Comment: It's winforms! (never used wpf)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIRC you can do the following:

`ASCII_FriendList.Items.Add(item);`

where `item` is *any* object (for example your object that contains `name` and `gameName`), the type of which I will refer to as `T`.

Then hook the `Format` event like so:

```
public Main()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ASCII_FriendList.Format += ASCII_FriendList_Format; //You can press tab at += in VS to auto-create the method body.
}


private void ASCII_FriendList_Format(object sender, ListControlConvertEventArgs e)
{
    //e.Value will be the string that will display in the list on the form.
    if(!(e.ListItem is T))
        e.Value = "ListItem isn't T"; //e.ListItem wasn't T, so we can't access gameName
    else
        e.Value = ((T)e.ListItem).gameName; //Cast e.ListItem to T, then access its gameName property
}
```

This will have `ASCII_FriendList.SelectedItem` be the object of type `T` (assuming you cast to it by doing `(T)ASCII_FriendList.SelectedItem`), while visibly displaying `T.gameName` in the form.